# Can a Context-free grammar exist, where all of its symbols are useless?

Tags: context-free-grammar

Let G be a context-free grammar, defined with terminals (a,b), starting at S, and having variables (A,B,C,D,E,F,G)

with these production rules:

```
S -> aA | BD
A -> aA | aAB | aD
B -> aB | aC | BF
C -> Bb | aAC | E
D -> bD | bC | b
E -> aB | bC
F -> aF | aG | a
G -> a | b
```

I tried to reduce first the non-generating symbols, removing A, B, C and E. 
Then after tracking the non-reachable symbols, I was left out with S -> nothing.

I have successfully dealt with tens of applications but this is the first case when my grammar self-implodes.

How can this be possible? Is there anything wrong I did? Are there any CFG with useless symbols only?

EDIT: I remind the algorithm's steps:
1) remove non-generating symbols (the generating X has one at least one derivation X -> w, where w is a string of terminals)
2) remove the non reachable symbols (X is reachable if S -> αXβ)

Comment: Step 1 of the algorithm in your edit us imprecise. The criterion is that X derives a (possibly empty) string consisting only of terminals, but the derivation does not have to be direct. So `A` is productive even though all of its productions include a non-terminal.

Comment: This is what I was waiting for! This is where my error came from. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Formal_definitions) of a context-free grammar does not require its symbols to be [reachable or productive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Useless_rules), although every context-free grammar can be transformed into a [<strike>weakly</strike> strongly equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_(formal_languages)) (thanks, **rici**) grammar with no useless symbols. However, since the [language of your grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Context-free_language) is nonempty, you probably applied the transformations incorrectly. For example, your grammar generates the string `aab`:

```
S ⇒ aA  (S → aA)
  ⇒ aaD (A → aD)
  ⇒ aab (D → b)
```

Comment: Please make the computation again, because I am really confused. In the process of removing the useless symbols, first the non-generating symbols are removed (the generating ones are of the form K -> w, where w is a string of terminals only). A, B,C and E are removed because they are non-productive, they don;t match any such derivation.

Comment: @alex I never performed the computation. I pointed out that there *are* grammars whose symbols are entirely useless, but that *you* must have applied the transformations incorrectly, because your grammar generates at least one string.

Comment: @alex No problem. If you want help with a specific algorithm, post your work.

Comment: Removing non-productive and unreachable symbols produces a strongly equivalent grammar. The removal doesn't affect any production which appears in any full derivation. So all derivations in the reduced grammar are equal (not just isomorphic; nothing is renamed) to the derivations for the same strings in the original grammar, which is a strong equivalence.

Comment: @rici That sounds right. I'm going to keep "weakly equivalent" in the answer because the standard references (e.g., Hopcroft and Ullman) only present proofs that the algorithms generate weakly equivalent grammars.

Comment: H&U are only interested in the language, not in the parse tree. But if you look at the proof for the result of removing useless symbols, you can see that it is based on the fact that the derivations are the same, not just the derived sentences. So if they had had the slightest interest and n strong equivalence, they could have used precisely the same proof.

Comment: @rici I looked over the proof from H&U and you're correct. Answer updated.